# Fastest way to SELECT record from MySql table that not exist inside other table

Tags: mysql

I have site with rating forms that's recognizing people with combination on IP and fingerprints based on UserAgent and dozens of properties.

When user rate some product, it send his mark to table rating containing his fingerprint too, which is long string like this:

```
cceda00975d0bfd57f629d9cce955842
```

Then site loads next product to rate,which cannot be the same as previous, so i have following query:

```
SELECT word FROM words 
WHERE word NOT IN (SELECT item FROM rating WHERE fingerprint='$fingerprint') 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

The problem is absurdly long loading time that is rising by number of records in rating table.

Can you give me some advice for better performance?Thx

Comment: Is there an index on the `fingerprint` column?

Comment: What indexes do you have on your tables?

Comment: Why are you using `ORDER BY RAND()`?

Comment: so far, none, because unfortunately I do not know how they work :)

Comment: hmm, youre right ORDER BY RAND is needless, probably Ive forgot it by copying from another project.I get rid of it, but i dont think it slows all process so much.

Comment: I think correct way to make it work fast will be in indexes, so Mark and aynber :) How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes help mysql find data in your tables much faster, much like an index in a book. You can add an index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE rating ADD INDEX fingerprint_idx(fingerprint);
```

**Edit** As Ollie said, other indexes might help as well.

To add a compound index (an index on multiple columns), use this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE rating ADD INDEX fingerprint_item_idx(fingerprint, item);
```

To add an index for the words column, use this:

```
ALTER TABLE words ADD INDEX word_idx(word);
```

Comment: Actually a compound index will help this query better: `fingerprint_idx(fingerprint, item)`. Also an index on `words.word` is likely to help.

Comment: Hmm, you're probably right. I'll update the answer with those indexes.

Comment: Thaks will try that, but can you tell me in which order is database searching with this query?It takes random word and then its searching if this word is not containing in table with ratings or it start search all words that are in table rating with that fingerprint search them in all words then exclude them and select one random word from the rest?

Comment: ive forgot to say my products database has about 20000 items

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with the inner workings of mysql to figure out which order it would go in. I would think it would use the inner select first, then use the results for the outer select, but I couldn't say for certain.

Comment: Ok, doesnt matter ill try to add indexes and and let you know if it helped, so far thanks

Comment: Can I have additional question?For now i have fingerprint as a text field Is it correct?Iam not sure bout that

Comment: TEXT would make the searches go slower. If the fingerprint isn't going to be longer than a certain length, then use VARCHAR. By default, VARCHAR is 255 characters, but you can modify it to be shorter or longer than that.

Comment: Ive used `ALTER TABLE rating ADD INDEX fingerprint_idx(fingerprint)` on whole table rating, but nothing happens , as I said i am not sure how indexes work is enough to use this command on existing table or i have to do that always when someone rate product?Ive also changed fingerprint to VARCHAR as you said

Comment: Sorry ma bad, when ive applied last index rule `ALTER TABLE rating ADD INDEX fingerprint_item_idx(fingerprint, item)` whole process gone down to about one second thanks a lot guys ;)